# Automatically Set "pokemonName" Field in ScriptableObject Based on Asset Name

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have a `PokemonBase` `ScriptableObject` in Unity that represents a Pokémon with various attributes. I want to automatically set the `pokemonName` field within the `ScriptableObject` to match the name of the asset when I create a new one.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewPokemon", menuName = "Pokemon/Create a new Pokemon")]
public class PokemonBase : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] string pokemonName;
    public string PokemonName
    {
        get{return pokemonName;}
        set{pokemonName=value;}
    }
    // ... other fields ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `OnValidate` method.

```
private void OnValidate()
{
    pokemonName = name;
}
```

`OnValidate` gets called when the script is loaded or a value changes in the Inspector.

If you need to update all of the existing scriptable objects names, then I would write an editor window that would load all of the scriptable objects and assign the pokemonName from there.  This may not be needed since `OnValidate` should run when the script is loaded.